# why spring handles only unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, spring, exception

I want to know why spring handles only unchecked exceptions..... can any one explain what is the reason behind this .

Spring is using any design patterns which will avoid checked exceptions ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Spring is using any design patterns which will avoid checked
>   exceptions ?

Not a design pattern but **Best Practices for Exception Handling**.

Consider below code:

```
public void consumeAndForgetAllExceptions(){
    try {
        ...some code that throws exceptions
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code above?

Once an exception is thrown, normal program execution is suspended and control is transferred to the catch block. The catch block catches the exception and just suppresses it. Execution of the program continues after the catch block, as if nothing had happened.

How about the following?

```
public void someMethod() throws Exception{
}
```

This method is a blank one; it does not have any code in it. *How can a blank method throw exceptions?* Java does not stop you from doing this.

> I want to know why spring handles only unchecked exceptions?

Personally I prefer unchecked exceptions declared in the throws cause. I hate having to catch exceptions when I'm not interested in them. I agree the spec needs to a few more exception types, but I disagree that they should be checked. Most frameworks rely on unchecked exceptions, not only Spring framework.

### Best Practices for Designing the API

- If the client can take some alternate action to recover from the exception, make it a *checked exception*.
- If the client cannot do anything useful, then make the *exception unchecked*. By useful, I mean taking steps to recover from the exception and not just logging the exception.

The Java API has many unchecked exceptions,
 such as 
`NullPointerException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, and `IllegalStateException`. I prefer working with standard exceptions provided in Java rather than creating my own. They make my code easy to understand and avoid increasing the memory footprint of code.

**See Also:**

- [Unchecked Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)
- [Best practices in exception handling](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/why-should-you-use-unchecked-exceptions.html)

Comment: Mostly I agree with your answer, especially the "Best Practices" part.  However, if unchecked exceptions are the ones where the client cannot take useful action, why declare them in the throws clause?  No useful action can be taken anyway.

Comment: Declaring unchecked exceptions in a method signature improves readability and also gives tools (like IDE) a chance to suggest useful catch blocks in code that calls such a method. It's really just a courtesy, but it can be pretty useful for callers.

Comment: How can a provider assume a client can or cannot do anything useful with an Exception?

Answer (score 6):

Spring's central theme is Dependency Injection and IOC. Checked exceptions add unncessary code and create more dependency. As such, the dependency costs of checked exceptions outweigh their benefits. They reduce the ability to test code. They lead to lower cohesion and higher coupling. The goal of your code should be high cohesion and low coupling. Spring is focused towards the S.O.L.I.D principles of design.