# How does UriComponentsBuilder avoid URISyntaxException?

Tags: java, spring, uri

How do Spring's `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder` and related `UriComponents.toUri()` avoid the checked exception `URISyntaxException` that occurs with the `java.net.URI` constructor?

For example, using `new URI()` results in having to catch the checked exception:

```
try {
  uri = new URI(myUrl);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
  // oops
}
```

vs. using Spring's builder avoids that:

```
uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(myUrl)
  .build()
  .toUri();
// no checked exception here
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it, they are being caught and converted to runtime `IllegalStateException` exceptions here:

- [HierarchicalUriComponents.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e3d0ef6/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/HierarchicalUriComponents.java#L434)
- [OpaqueUriComponents.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/73cf07e/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/OpaqueUriComponents.java#L140)

As for motivation, Spring favors runtime exceptions generally: [why spring handles only unchecked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178952/why-spring-handles-only-unchecked-exceptions)